# What is the most popular running (and fitness) application for mobile devices?

Tags: running, technology

I have used runtastic and Daily Mile and of course there is Garmin, but what mobile applications besides these are most popular for running and/or fitness and why? I'm looking to see what other features are out there that I don't have.

Comment: Voted as off-topic as running for recreational and fitness purposes is off-topic for this site and should be asked in [F&N](http://fitness.stackexchange.com). Running questions must specifically relate to competitive running.

Comment: Voted to close as not constructive since questions of type "What is the best..." typically yield subjective answers and a long discussion instead of a definitive answer.

Comment: @Dmitry but it's not asking for the best. It's asking for the most popular, which has an objective response. Although there are multiple ways to measure popularity (user count, average satisfaction rating, average word-of-mouth recommendations) answers can be grounded in facts and references.

Comment: @glowcoder I can see where you are coming from and I tried arguing this before but most of the time questions like this turn into a mess unfortunately.

Comment: @MarcusSwope You seem to imply that for competitive sports - here running - you will not be using these applications? Is that really true? I expect many to use their mobile devices instead of a dedicated device such as Garmin. Or? I vote to re-open.

Comment: How can we compare this question to http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/86/38

Comment: @TonnyMadsen this question isn't constructive because it ask for a product recommendation. Its a shopping question, not because it has to do with running.

Comment: @TonnyMadsen it's not because of what the question is about, it is what it isn't about. Running and applications that help people run are definitely on topic, but I don't see in the question where this has to do specifically with competitive running, it seems to me to be more about running for recreational or fitness purposes. If the question was edited to address competitive running (as well as not be a shopping question as wax eagle noted) then I would vote to re-open.

Comment: @MarcusSwope - If you keep closing topics stating that they aren't constructive and/or should be located elsewhere, what's the purpose of the site? Most of the questions asked can be defined as not constructive. Many have wikipedia answers and/or can be found using a simple Google search.

Comment: @DmitrySelitskiy - If you keep closing topics stating that they aren't constructive and/or should be located elsewhere, what's the purpose of the site? Most of the questions asked can be defined as not constructive. Many have wikipedia answers and/or can be found using a simple Google search.

Comment: @JasonN.Gaylord this was discussed [in meta](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/30/competitive-or-recreational-running), we are still trying to come up with clear definition of what is on-topic and what is off-topic, especially with running.

Comment: @Marcus: and I don't feel that "it has to be competitive" is as clear a consensus as you imply in your first comment.

Comment: @JasonN.Gaylord I'm not _closing_ but am _voting_ to close which is how this site is designed: we as a community decide which questions we want to encourage and which ones not to.

Comment: @DmitrySelitskiy But for a new stack exchange site to have 10%+ of it's questions closed, I think the moderators (in which I felt I should be one as the running proposal was mine) need to clearly define what should be in here.

Comment: @JasonN.Gaylord see the note under the question: not moderators close questions - community does collectively (i.e. 5 people voted to close and the system closes it automatically). It's not a mod's decision.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [Nike+ iPod/iPhone app](http://www.apple.com/ipod/nike/), which according to [Nike](http://investors.nikeinc.com/Theme/Nike/files/doc_financials/2012Q1.pdf):

> Nike+ has 5 million users.

There are a number of Nike shoes that contain the requisite sensor/chip, and some third parties, such as [Polar](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/polar-and-nike-introduce-heart-rate-training-to-millions-of-nike-runners-95766249.html), have provided accessories that work with the Nike system.

Comment: There's also a Nike+ GPS app which doesn't require an external sensor.

Comment: You don't need to have Nike+ specific shoes now either, both Marware (big fan of theirs) and SwitchEasy make accessories that can fit with any shoe.

Comment: The Nike+ app is great, but still is a very bad choice, because the day you will need to ski or bike you will have to find another app.