# How to start running

Tags: running

I didn't run many years. I swim in a pool. Now I am feeling I need to start running. Have someone suggest me how to start running from scratch? I am 35 years old.

PS. The strength and spirit, I have :).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question seem better suited for our [Fitness & Nutrition](http://fitness.stackexchange.com) exchange, and less so here, where we talk about the "Sport" of running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start easy!

Run for 5 minutes, then walk for 5 minutes, repeat...

When you have done this for some time and it feels comfortable you can start running without walking breaks.

Remember don't increase distance or speed with more than 10% per week to avoid injuries.

Answer (score 6):

[C25K](http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/2/2_3/181.shtml) ? I liked it.
It is comprehensive and the workouts are geared towards  beginners.

Comment: I started running last year with a C25K program and I haven't stopped. Great intro program with a steady ramp up.

Comment: Agree 100%. I started the program in October at 70+ lbs. overweight, and unable to run even a minute without feeling like I was going to die. I've had to repeat weeks of the workout, but I can now easily run 20 minutes with no walking. It's definitely manageable. There are a lot of music podcasts out there with voice cues, or you can use an app like Runkeeper and program the intervals yourself so you can listen to your own music. Being able to see my progress on the Runkeeper website over the course of the months definitely has kept me going at times when I wanted to quit.

Answer (score 5):

I just started running after playing volleyball for years. First few weeks were fine, but after a few weeks it became difficult for me to find the spirit to exercise. What worked for me was:

- Install Runkeeper or any other GPS tracking device on my phone to be able to track progress
- Find a running group in your area. I exercise once a week with this group. They give me great tips and I made a lot of friends.
- See if you can find any matches nearby. This motivated me to improve. You'll also meet nice people!

Comment: Running with friends is an amazing way to get through long runs.  The time flies, and suddenly you realize you are 20K into a run.